# Edit & Auto Reload CSS Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am editing my webpage for testing locally on the Google Chrome DevTools and I would like the new CSS rules to be saved and reloaded any time I'm in this webpage even after reload or moving to another webpage at the same domain.

Actually I want to include a css file located on my local drive every time I'm inside a specific domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve your goal using a DevTools Workspace. Have a look at the [getting started document](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#workspace).